# qcut for Decile and Interval Bins

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

Market X :

| Decile | Interval | Score(min) | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (0.633532, 0.949047] | 0.633533 | 148790 |
| 2 | (0.558736, 0.633532] | 0.558736 | 148790 |

I am grouping by market x and using qcut to apply a decile to scores as well as an interval bin. However the interval  is represented by the '(' as an excluded floor of decile 2 shows a min value of the exact match. One other decile also has this issue wtihin the 10.  What am I missing here:

Decile Code:

```
df_scored['Decile'] = df_scored.groupby([market],dropna=False)[score].transform(
                      lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10 ,precision=6, labels= 
                      [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])).astype(int)
```

Interval Code:

```
df_scored['Interval'] = df_scored.groupby(market,dropna=False)[score].apply(pd.qcut, 10 ,precision=6)
```